# How to add numbers to an array except if the number in the array matches a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, list-comprehension

I want to add a certain number to values of my arrays, with a maximum capping out at 255, but only in cases where the number in the array does not match 0.

Imagine the value I want to add to each number in my array is 20, except if number is 0

```
#The array to which I want to add a number based on value:
v=array([0,0,0,0,117,119,120,121,16,1,16,10,245,0,0,0,4,5])

value=20
lim = 255 - value 
v[v > lim] = 255
v[v <= lim] += value

#Results in the following array
array([20,20,20,20,137,139,140,141,36,21,36,30,255,20,20,20,24,25])
```

This works, but also adds when the number is 0. However, I want to have a statement in there, that adds 20 in all cases, except if the number in the array is 0! Expected outcome:

```
array([0,0,0,0,137,139,140,141,36,21,36,30,255,0,0,0,24,25])
```

Wasn't able to find a good solution or figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it following way:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([0,0,0,0,117,119,120,121,16,1,16,10,245,0,0,0,4,5])
value = 20
lim = 255
v += (v!=0)*value
v = np.clip(v, None, lim)
print(list(v))
```

output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 137, 139, 140, 141, 36, 21, 36, 30, 255, 0, 0, 0, 24, 25]
```

Explanation: I treat boolean array of where there are non-zero as array of `0`s and `1`s, thus by multiplying by `value` I get value to add for each element, then I use [numpy.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to replace values beyond `lim`.

Comment: A very creative solution, would have never come to my mind!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `v[v <= lim] += value` with `v[(v != 0) & (v <= lim)] += value`

Comment: Thanks! Works as a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use these two lines to achieve your expected output

- add 20 to all non zero values `v[(v!=0)] += 20`
- cap out values to 255 `v[v > 255] = 255`

Complete Code:

```
v= np.array([0,0,0,0,117,119,120,121,16,1,16,10,245,0,0,0,4,5])
value=20
lim = 255
v[v!=0] += value
v[v>lim] = lim
print(v)
```

```
>> [  0   0   0   0 137 139 140 141  36  21  36  30 255   0   0   0  24  25]
```

Comment: You made the entire solution more efficient. Thanks